# Can please anybody explain me this Autoboxing?

Tags: java, oracle, scjp, autoboxing

Alright, here's the code :

```
public class Dec26 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        short a1=6;
        new Dec26.go(a1);
        new Dec26.go(new Integer(7));
    }
    void go(Short x){System.out.println("S");}
    void go(Long x){System.out.println("L");}
    void go(int x){System.out.println("i");}
    void go(Number n){System.out.println("N");}
}
```

Why is the output "iN" and not "ii" ?

Comment: If you are reading Kathy Sierra exam book then the explanation given there is crisp. Widening is preferred over boxing/unboxing. Do you have any other confusion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Java compiler applies unboxing when an object of a wrapper class is:

- Passed as a parameter to a method that expects a value of the
  corresponding primitive type.
- Assigned to a variable of the corresponding primitive type.

So, as there was a suitable method for Integer class, which is `void go(Number n)` because `Number` class is super class of `Integer` and this method accepts `Integer` objects as well.
So  compiler didn't need to unbox the `Integer` to `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler chooses the closest match  without autoboxing /unboxing first. It found go(Number) and did not use unboxing.